# GitStack Install: "An other service is already using the port 80. Please stop this service during the installation of GitStack."

Tags: git, gitstack

I've stopped IIS and SQL Server Reporting Services and the GitStack install STILL complains about port 80.

I downloaded TCPView and the only HTTP processes listening are System(PID=4) and TCPView kill doesn't seem to have any ability to actually kill the system (not sure if it even should).

Any ideas?  The GitStack.com WordPress Q/A isn't letting me post a question directly on that site.

Comment: maybe try to change GitStack's port to something else? btw gitblit is another alternative witch works just out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

1. Launch RegEdit
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
3. Change the value of "start" to 4 (disabled)
4. Reboot your computer